# How to calculate $n$ in $f = p^n - q^n$?

Tags: exponentiation

I have the formula:

$f(n) = \frac{p^n - q^n}{\sqrt 5}$

Assuming I know the value of $f(n)$, can I calculate $n$?

Sure, I can convert to $ \sqrt 5*f(n) = p^n - q^n$ . But after that I stuck...

---

edit 1

$p = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$

$q = \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2}$

Comment: Is $n$ necessarily a natural number? And do you have $p$ and $q$? Are they integers?

Comment: n is not necessary an integer. I have the values of p and q, yes. Addded in the description.

Comment: $q$ is negative, so $q^n$ will be complex if $n$ is not an integer. In other words, when $f_n$ is real, there will be no solutions other than in those cases where $f_n$ is Fibonacci, and then the solutions are (uniquely) determined easily.

Comment: You can't always do this. We have that $f(1)=f(2)=1$ so given $f(n)=1$ there is no formula which will give a definite result. For large $n$ we have that $q^n$ is very small and taking logarithms gives an accurate estimate (nearest integer) for $f(n)\ge 2$ where $f(n)$ is a fibonacci number.

Comment: Use this [trinomial series solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial) to get the general inverse function

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume $n$ is an integer as otherwise I don't know how to interpret $q^n$. then $f(n)$ is also an integer, and because $|q|<1$ for large $n$ (in fact $n>1$) you have
$$f(n)=\frac{p^n-q^n}{\sqrt{5}}=\left[\frac{p^n}{\sqrt{5}}\right],$$
where $[x]$ denotes the nearest integer to $x$. This shows that
$$n\approx\log_p(\sqrt{5}f(n)).$$

Comment: It is a really good approximation, thank you.

Comment: Can we assume, taking a rounded $n$ from your formula, that $fibonacci(n)$ would be equal to the n-th fibonacci?

Comment: @Arthur edited to "rounded n"

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f(n)$ is real. Then there will be  no solutions for the problem, other than in the case  where $n$ is integer which entails that $f(n)$ is a Fibonacci number.

Proof:

Observe $q = \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2} <0$. So $q^n = \left(\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{2}\right)^n \cdot  e^{i \pi n}$ where the first factor is a positive real. Now the imaginary part of $e^{i \pi n}$ vanishes only for integer $n$. This leads to two cases:

(1) let $n$ not be an integer. Then $p^n$ is real and $q^n$ has a nonvanishing imaginary part, so for real $f(n)$, there is no solution to $f(n) = \frac{p^n - q^n}{\sqrt 5}$.

(2) let $n$ be integer. Then $f(n) = \frac{p^n - q^n}{\sqrt 5}$ is exactly Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers, which are the only cases where there is a solution for real $f(n)$.  Since for $n>1$, the Fibonacci series $f(n)$ is strictly monotonously increasing, $n$ is uniquely determined. Servaes's answer gives a nice clue to find $n\approx\log_p(\sqrt{5}f(n))$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andreas has pointed out, the function $f(n) = (\varphi^n - (-\varphi)^{-n})/\sqrt 5$ is not real-valued unless $n$ is an integer.  So typically one would be interested in replacing $f(n)$ with [its real part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Extension_to_all_real_or_complex_numbers), which is well-defined and entire:

$$ g(x) = \Re f(x) = \frac{\varphi^x - \cos(\pi x)\varphi^{-x}}{\sqrt 5} $$

See also the discussion at previous Question [Non integer Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798190/non-integer-fibonacci-numbers) and its earlier linked Question [Interpolated Fibonacci numbers - real or complex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589841/interpolated-fibonacci-numbers-real-or-complex)

In any case $g(x)$ is real-valued for $x$ real and monotone increasing for $x\ge 2$, so solutions to $g(x) = k$ can be uniquely determined for $x\in[2,+\infty)$ for all integers $k\ge 1$.  Although $g(x)$ is a transcendental function, it is analytic in the complex plane; Newton iterations will converge rapidly given reasonable initial estimates for root $x$.

In particular since [the OP commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170645/how-to-calculate-n-in-f-pn-qn/3170656?noredirect=1#comment6528176_3170656) on Servaes' Answer, "$f(n)$ is always integer in my problem,"  the initial estimate given there will be adequate for large $k\gg 1$:

$$ x \approx \log_\varphi (k \sqrt 5) $$

For modest positive integers $k$ it might be worthwhile to [identify whether $k$ is Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Identification), and if not, to bracket $k$ with its nearest lower/upper Fibonacci numbers to interpolate an initial guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a general way of solving this exactly. You might be in luck with your specific values of $p$ and $q$, but i doubt it. Unless $f(n)$ is a Fibonacci number, I'd just go with approximations, numerical methods or online calculators like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) for each specific value of $f(n)$.

Comment: The connection with [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Identification) is worth exploring in greater detail, as it seems possible that Binet's formula does lead to a more explicit solution when "$f(n)$ is a Fibonacci number".

Comment: @hardmath If $f_n$ is Fibonacci, then by Binet we have exactly $f(n)=\frac{p^n-q^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, with the $p,q$ given by OP.  Since for $n>1$, $f_n$ is strictly monotonously increasing, $n$ is uniquely determined and this is the solution (directly).

Comment: @Andreas Most of that argument carries over for non-fibonacci $f(n)$ as well. It's just that if $f(n)$ happens to be fibonacci, then we know $n$ is an integer, and that makes the search for the solution much easier. But even for $f(n) = 43$, say, there is only one solution with $n>1$. It's a lot harder to find, but it's there.

Comment: Well, for all real $f(n)$ which are not Fibonacci there are no solutions at all since if $n$ is not integer, $p^n$ is real and $q^n$ is complex, so the RHS is complex and this is a contradiction to real $f(n)$.

Comment: @Andreas I missed that $q$ was negative. Cool.

Comment: $f(n)$ is always integer in my problem. But its cool to follow your thought process guys

Comment: I'll put that into a full answer.

Comment: Forgetting Fibonacci numbers, the problem of $p^x-q^x=k$ is very interesting from a numerical point of view if $1 < q < p$ and $k>0$. We could get an estimate very close to the solution.